# Mathematical Tables in Babbage's Library

Tags: ho.history-overview

DeMorgan authored the entry under TABLES in both the Penny and English Cyclopedias. Copies of a number of the tables DeMorgan discusses were in the library of Charles Babbage, a resource to which DeMorgan seems to have had access.

Questions:

1) Is there a list of the books in Babbage's Library somewhere?

2) What happened to the library upon Babbage's death?

Thanks for any insight.

Cheers, Scott

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See: M.R. Williams, "The Scientific Library of Charles Babbage," *IEEE Annals of the History of Computing*, vol. 3, no. 3, pp. 235-240, July-Sept. 1981, doi:10.1109/MAHC.1981.10028

Abstract: "In the early nineteenth century, Charles Babbage compiled a large scientific library that included many rare works. This paper describes the history, contents, and present location of the library. The contents are classified under twenty-one headings."